# Bullet Physics - btConvexShape to Softbody

Tags: bulletphysics

I have a simple question: How do I convert a `btConvexShape` to a `btSoftBody`? By using `btSoftBodyHelpers::CreateFromConvexHull`? If so, I'm not clear on how I pass the convex hull to the softbody helper based on bullets documentation for the [helper](http://bulletphysics.org/Bullet/BulletFull/structbtSoftBodyHelpers.html#a33f3787c9208680112c66fa8b1757c77) and [convex shape](http://bulletphysics.org/Bullet/BulletFull/classbtConvexShape.html)

Answer (score 0):

btConvexShape can be any convex object in bullet, not just a convex hull. You should implement different approaches depending on the concrete subclass. Use btCollisionShape::getShapeType() ([return values](http://bulletphysics.org/Bullet/BulletFull/btBroadphaseProxy_8h.html#a629e290d766e52966199b687a537ba5e)) to find out the concrete implementation, then cast. Eg:

```
btSoftBody* convexShapeToSoft(const btConvexShape& shape)
{
    if(shape.getShapeType() == BOX_SHAPE_PROXYTYPE)
    {
        const btBoxShape& boxShape = static_cast<const btBoxShape&>(shape);

        // Build btSoftBody using the box vertices
    }
    else if(shape.getShapeType() == SPHERE_SHAPE_PROXYTYPE)
    {
        const btSphereShape& shpereShape = static_cast<const btSphereShape&>(shape);

        // Build btSoftBody using the box vertices
    }
    // ....
}
```